# python get all kinds of strings

Tags: python, string

I have a substring in python such as "Hello_world", It can be given in any format like "hello_world" or "HELLO_WORLD" or "heLLo_World" etc. There may be a change in capitalizing of letters. I have a string and I am splitting the string at the above given substring. I read about the package `re` (regular expressions) through some of the stack overflow questions. Can I achieve the above purpose with it??

Is there any possible way to perform above operation  ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not clear of what do you want to do with the string, could you give more details? Thanks!

Comment: I think he means he has a large string, inside of which is the substring `hello_world`, which can be in any capitalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While yes, you can use regular expressions for this problem, Python provides far simpler string functions for such tasks. Here is an example on the command line:

```
>>> my_string = 'There is a HeLLO_worLD in this string'
>>> 'hello_world' in my_string.lower()
True
```

Comment: I think he wants to do more than just find the substring.

Comment: I agree splitting the string is not covered by this answer. The answer can be edited once more information is available. This example does highlight that `re` may not be required.

Comment: @JohnGordon yes you are right but got some idea from above answer thanks Alex Taylor

Answer (score 1):

Use the `re.IGNORECASE` flag in `re.split()`:

```
import re

def isplit(myString, mySubstring):
    return re.split(mySubString, myString, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

myString = "HellO_World"
mySubString = "o_w"
isplit(myString, mySubstring)
# gives ['Hell', 'orld']
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to lowercase before comparing. If `s`  is the string do `s.lower()` before comparing.

Answer (score 0):

So if you're splitting, use `re.split`:

```
import re

s = re.split(r"(?i)hello_world", "aaaa hELLo_worLd bbbb HELLo_woRld cccc")
print(s)
```

```
['aaaa ', ' bbbb ', ' cccc']
```